# Loading a model with Name in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to load models into a view. i am able to load the model when i do not give any name for the model like:-

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("mao").setModel(oModel);
```

But the model is not set to view if i give like the below. I am not getting any error also

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("mao").setModel(oModel,"myModel");
```

I am using load data to load my data

```
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.loadData(servicePath);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("mao").setModel(oModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData(servicePath);

var oController = this;

oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
     var data = oModel.getData();
     oController.getView().setModel(data, "namedModel");
});
```

Then you can call like so:

```
this.getView().getModel("namedModel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding paths in the view should also be adjusted for named model binding. Details please see
at [documentaion](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0ed206f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) regarding the binding path.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set a model to a view is by defining them in Component.js file or if you are using 1.33 and above version then define the model in manifest.json file.

- Set Model in Component.js file:
  Define the model init method as shown below:

  ```
  sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/ui/core/UIComponent'],
  function(jQuery, UIComponent) {
  "use strict";

  var Component = UIComponent.extend("samples.components.sample.Component", {
  metadata : {
  }
  init: function() {
     var sServiceUrl = 'example/servie';
     var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel (sServiceUrl, true);
     this.setModel (oModel, "modelName");
  }
  });
  return Component;
  });
  ```
- Set the model in manifest.json file
  https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html

Now this model will be available in any controller and you can access the model as mentioned below:

```
  var oModel = this.getView().getModel("modelName");
```

Answer (score 0):

`this._sValidPath =jQuery.sap.getModulePath("OpenUI.c", "/name.pdf");
   this._oModel = new JSONModel({
        Source: this._sValidPath,
        Title: "My Custom Title",
        Height: "600px"
    });
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(this._oModel,"mainModel2");`

Answer (score -1):

> sap.ui.getCore().byId("mao").setModel(oModel);
>
> But the model is not set to view if i give like the below.

You did not bind this to the View you bound it to the core.
Remove the .byId("mao") and it should work.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData(servicePath);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "myModelName");
```

Read Model:

```
var oMyModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("myModelName");
```

sap.ui.getCore().byId("mao").setModel("myModel") means you want to get a object by the ID "mao" and assign a model to the object.

This is how the view binding works:

```
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "myModelName");
var oMyModel = this.getView().getModel("myModelName");
```

On the OpenUI5 site theres a nice developer walkthrough check this out: 
https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409.html